# Logstash filter date to match particular date format

Tags: timestamp, logstash

I am parsing some logs with logstash, while I match the date easily for the logs of application A with this format

```
 2014-06-06 10:38:07,855
```

I am using this filter :

```
filter{
grok {
            patterns_dir => "./patterns"
            match=>["message","%{APPLICATION_A:log_timestamp}"]
        }

date {
        match=>["log_timestamp","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
}
```

The pattern used is

APPLICATION_A (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})

I would like to know how to do with this format of logs timestamp

```
2014-Jun-06 10:38:07,855
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are simply looking for

```
date {
    match => ["log_timestamp","YYYY-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    locale => "en"
}
```

Mind the three (3) `M` as matcher for month, and set the locale to `en` to match english month names.